# Make Vertical Line With HTML CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, line

I've noticed vertical lines like in the website [trippeo.com](http://trippeo.com) if you scroll down to where it says "increase traveler loyalty..." and then has a vertical line below. How would you create a  long line like that in web design? Would you need to make an image and absolute position it or is there a better way with HTML, CSS, and or JavaScript?

Comment: Use `border` property of css

Comment: there are many ways of doing that, you should provide context on your use case so we can answer clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in two ways:

1. **Background Image aligned to right and repeated across y-axis.**

   ```css
   .main-liner {background: url("bg.png") repeat-y right top transparent;}
   ```
2. **Border**

   ```css
   .main-liner {border-right: 2px solid #f00; margin-right: -2px;}
   ```

#### Preview:

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/RU42F/

Comment: you could also use pseudo elements

Comment: yes, you are right for IE8- but it is the technique used in the linked site by the OP.